# React Native: Cannot position Image with resizeMode "contain" at the flex-end of parent component

Tags: react-native, image

So I'm trying to animate two images by sliding them out of the screen in opposite directions in React Native. The 2 images are positioned side by side, **with each image's parent component taking up 50% of the screen width**. I want the images to be positioned next to each other without any gap between them, AND they also have to use `resizeMode="contain"` to ensure that the images **scale proportionally** to fit within their respective containers, **while preserving their aspect ratios**.

I have tried everything that I can think of to position the left-hand Image component to the very end of its parent component, and the right-hand Image to the very start of its parent component so that they would touch each other but nothing seems to work. The images are always positioned at the center of their respective containers as shown in the image bellow.

1. On the **left side** I have the left half of the image which I want to position at the very end of its **blue container**.
2. On the **right side** I have the right half of the image which I want to position at the very start of its **red container**.

[image]

Here is my JSX code:

```
return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: width / 2,
            height: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            transform: [{ translateX: leftTranslateX }],
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={leftSplash}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: width / 2,
            height: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
            transform: [{ translateX: rightTranslateX }],
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={rightSplash}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
  );
```

Comment: Where does each image start? Or are they not animated yet?

Comment: Do you have a sample video of what you want?

Comment: The images in the photo are not yet animated. This is what my screen looks like before the animation starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if understand correctly this is what your screen looks like before the animation starts, and you want the image in the blue container to touch the image in the red container.

Your Problem is that you are using `width: '100%'` in your Image components. To fix the issue **you'll have to calculate the width of your images in pixels** dynamically when the component loads. You'll then replace the '100%' values in both images with the afformentioned pixel values.

Here's a code example:

```
// Calculate the width of each image based on its aspect ratio.
const leftImageWidthScaled = containerHeight * (leftSplashImage.width / leftSplashImage.height);
const rightImageWidthScaled = containerHeight * (rightSplashImage.width / rightSplashImage.height);

<Image
   source={leftSplashImage}
   style={{ width: leftImageWidthScaled, height: '100%', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>

<Image
   source={leftSplashImage}
   style={{ width: leftImageWidthScaled, height: '100%', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>
```